# Differentiability for a function from $\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $$f(x) = \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       \frac{x_1^3}{||x||}, & x\neq0 \\
>       0, & x =0 \\
> \end{array} 
> \right.$$ Show that $f$ is differentiable at the origin.

What is the definition for differentiability for a function from $\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$? It would satisfy that if all the partial derivatives were continuous right? I assume there's a different way to look at this also?

Edit: Typo in the numerator.

Comment: What is $x_1$? Also $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R^3$ and you speak of $f(x,y)$. Can you fix that?

Comment: Your function is not differentiable at at the origin.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Fixed! Also $x_1$ was given in the problem statement, I assume that the function would be $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ since it's from $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: For the differentiability of a map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$, a good analysis course will do the job or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you elaborate a bit, how is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

For the differentiability of several real variables maps, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions).

Your map is not differentiable at the origin as it is not even continuous. $f(x_1,0,0) = 1$ for $x_1 >0$  and $f(x_1,0,0) = -1$ for $x_1 <0$.

Comment: Apologies there was a typo on the numerator...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the definition. Note that

> Let $f: A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a function, $x_{0}\in A$ be a point, and let $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a linear transformation. We say that $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$ with derivate $T$ if we have
> $$\lim_{x\to x_{0};x\in A-\{x_{0}\}} \frac{||f(x)-(f(x_{0})+T(x-x_{0})) ||}{||x-x_{0}||}=0$$
> Here, $||x||$, is the length of $x$.

Comment: How do I find $T$?